# What am I? I am in theaters and computer programs

Tags: riddle, word

> I am in theaters
>   and in computer programs
>   I sometimes throw things,
>   and at other times help fix broken parts.
>   When away I might reject you,
>   but on election day you are sure to hear from me.

What am I?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Cast/Casting

I am in theaters

> Casting for a role

and in computer programs

> Casting/Typecasting (f.e. integer to string)

I sometimes throw things,

> To cast = to throw

and at other times help fix broken parts.

> Putting a broken limb in cast helps healing.

When away I might reject you,

> If you don't show up at casting you might get rejected.

but in election day you are sure to hear from me.

> You can cast your vote/ballot.

Comment: "Break a leg" is often said to actors. This may hint to a better answer to one of the lines.

Comment: @pt314 Thank you! Just edited my answer according your suggestion.

Comment: This is correct! There is a better explanation for the 5th line too.

Comment: Line 5 - maybe this: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0162222/ ?

Comment: line 5: rot13 pnfg bss = gb yrnir (tb njnl), be n erwrpg

Comment: throw things might be an error in programming when cast fails

Comment: Line 5--likely a reference to [this phrase](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cast_away).

Comment: Now who came in first - you or @ChrisPott ?

Comment: (This answer was first by about two minutes)

Answer (score 15):

**Edit:** Answer before new lines added.

I think the answer might be

> Method

I am in theaters

> [Method acting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_acting)

and in computer programs

> [Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)) - a procedure in object-oriented programming

I sometimes throw things,

> In computer programming, methods can *throw* [exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Exception_handling_in_software)

and at other times help fix broken parts.

> By definition, a method is a particular procedure for accomplishing or approaching something, especially a systematic or established one, this can include fixing broken items.

Comment: OP edited some more lines into their question. Seems like your answer isn't right, but they could have commented here to let you know ...

Comment: I like your answer but it isn't quite right

Answer (score 9):

> cast

I am in theaters

> the cast

and in computer programs

> cast exceptions

I sometimes throw things

> cast

and at other times help fix broken parts

> plaster cast

When away I might reject you

> castaway

but in election day you are sure to hear from me

> cast a vote

Comment: this is the best one so far

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer might be

> Call

I am in theaters

> Casting calls for roles

and in computer programs

> Calls to methods or functions

I sometimes throw things,

> Programming: calls to functions can *throw* Exceptions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Exception_handling_in_software)

and at other times help fix broken parts.

> Could be a call to or from a technician

when away I might reject you

> You can reject phone calls.

but in election day you are sure to hear from me.

> Robocalls for candidates

Comment: Ah, not the right answer but close!

Answer (score 5):

Could it be

> Mock

I am in theaters

> Mock play

and in computer programs

> Mock testing

I sometimes throw things,

> Mock exceptions

but in election day you are sure to hear from me.

> Mock elections

Comment: as I see you are struggling getting your answer well formatted. you can add <br> to make a newline ;)

Comment: Besides that though, welcome to Puzzling SE! Very creative ;)

Answer (score 4):

Are you:

> [Bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacteria)

I am in theaters

> Operating theaters, although you shouldn't be

and in computer programs

> as viruses

I sometimes throw things,

> projectile [vomiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vomiting) caused by unhealthy bacteria

and at other times help fix broken parts.

> benign bacteria can help the body heal, for example, [yoghurt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogurt).

When away I might reject you,

> a reference to [chemotaxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemotaxis). WPQuote: This is important for bacteria to . . . flee from poisons.

but in election day you are sure to hear from me.

> [irritable bowel syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irritable_bowel_syndrome) is often caused by bacteria.

Comment: I added some more lines to the riddle

Comment: @pirate; I noticed :)

Answer (score 3):

I am in theaters

> Routine - actors and dancers have [routines](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/routine). Comedians have routines, which is an act.

and in computer programs

> Routine - computers have [routines](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/routine). A program that is run repeatedly.

I sometimes throw things,

> Routine - a throwing routine for catchers? still looking

and at other times help fix broken parts.

> Routine - a routine can be used to [run maintenance on something](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/routine).

When away I might reject you,

> Routine - when you're away you no longer have a routine

but in election day you are sure to hear from me.

> Routine - not sure still searching. They have routine elections in some countries.

Comment: Hi, @Yvette Colomb Welcome on P.SE :)

Comment: @Mukyuu thanks! the HNQ drew me in :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's

> Exit

I am in theaters

> Exit stage left, exit signs are ubiquitous in theaters.

and in computer programs

> All programs can exit either smoothly...

I sometimes throw things,

> ... or by throwing an error.

and at other times help fix broken parts.

> If a program gives helpful error information while exiting, it can help to fix the program.

When away I might reject you,

> You may be rejected trying to enter into an "Exit Only" door.

but in election day you are sure to hear from me.

> Exit polls are often used to predict election results before the votes are tallied.

Answer (score 0):

I am in theaters

> Lights.  Foot lights, spot lights, flood lights.

and in computer programs

> The best debugging is only possible when light shines into the dark places where the bugs hide.

I sometimes throw things,

> Solar sails!  Laser propulsion.

and at other times help fix broken parts.

> Laser welding.

When away I might reject you,

> When you are depressed and sitting in the dark.

but in election day you are sure to hear from me.

> The light of truth as revealed by the poles.